# How to target the href to div

Tags: html, css

Here i am trying to open and get the contents of one div to target div on-click on a href.
Here i have table where i have hrefs which has the link to div ids, and i have an target div which is empty.

when i click the href links, the linked div contents should open in the target div.

for ex:
for link `fea1` i have linked id `#m1`, when i click the `fea1`, the `#m1` contents should appear in target div.

How can i do this???

here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Example
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>

        <table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <hr>
              <a href="#m1">
                fea1
              </a>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <a href="#m2">
                fea2
              </a>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <a href="#m3">
                fea3
              </a>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <a href="#m4">
                fea4
              </a>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <a href="#m5">
                fea5
              </a>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <a href="#m6">
                fea6
              </a>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <a href="#m7">
                fea7
              </a>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <a href="#m8">
                fea8
              </a>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <a href="#m9">
                fea9
              </a>
              <hr>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


        <div class="target">

        </div>


        <div id="m1">
          dasdasdasd
        </div>
        <div id="m2">
          dadasdasdasd
        </div>
        <div id="m3">
          sdasdasds
        </div>
        <div id="m4">
          dasdasdsad
        </div>
        <div id="m5">
          dasdasd
        </div>
        <div id="m6">
          asdasdad
        </div>
        <div id="m7">
          asdasda
        </div>
        <div id="m8">
          dasdasd
        </div>
        <div id="m9">
          dasdasdsgaswa
        </div>        
      </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

.target{
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    border:solid black 1px; 
}

#m1, #m2, #m3, #m4, #m5, #m6, #m7, #m8, #m9{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Where your javascript code?

Comment: @Pilot i have not used JavaScript code for this

Comment: OMG then how are you doing this?..

Comment: Why? I would have thought it essential!

Comment: I dont think this would be possible without Javascript.

Comment: You have to think about Javascript. Do you want something to do with tab options? like the Jquery (javascript library) http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @LearningNeverStops yes it is some thing like that. When i click some link, the linked element should appear in target div.

Comment: @MithunRaikar: You should consider using Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: @RahulDesai "Consider" is an understatement... AFAIK it is impossible without Javascript

Comment: IMHO, the `A` tag and `href` attribute is a really bad pair to use for this, as they already have defined behariour - i.e the page will scroll to that position. I would instead add a user-defined attribute to a div. I would also attach an onclick event handler to all of the target divs. I'll put together an example.

Comment: Do you have to *move* the contents from one div to the other? Showing/hiding a div based on hash and corresponding ID would have the same visual effect, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hn3U7/

Comment: Oh, you removed the javascript tag. Does that mean you want to find a solution *without* JavaScript?

Comment: @FelixKling it doesn't mean that... i was looking for a simple solution.

Comment: Well, tags usually indicate which technologies the solution can make use of. So if you remove the javascript tag, it means you are looking for solutions without JavaScript. If that wasn't your intention, you should add it back.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can put all your `#m1`...`#m9` divs into `.target` and display them based on fragment identifier (hash) using [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget) pseudo-class. It doesn't move the contents between divs, but I think the effect is close to what you wanted to achieve.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hn3U7/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="target">
    <div id="m1">
        dasdasdasd m1
    </div>
    <!-- etc... -->
    <div id="m9">
        dasdasdsgaswa m9
    </div>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.target {
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    border:solid black 1px; 
}
.target > div {
    display:none;
}

.target > div:target{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: You should mention that `:target` isn't supported in IE8 and below. Otherwise, good job!

Comment: how to do the same in bootstrap ?

Answer (score 6):

From what I know this will not be possible only with css. Heres a solution how you could make it work with jQuery which is a javascript Library. More about jquery here: http://jquery.com/

Here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/uyDbL/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        var aID = $(this).attr('href');
        var elem = $(''+aID).html();

        $('.target').html(elem);
    });
});
```

**Update 2018** (as this still gets upvoted) here is a plain javascript solution without jQuery

```js
var target = document.querySelector('.target');
[...document.querySelectorAll('table a')].forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
        target.innerHTML = document.querySelector(element.getAttribute('href')).innerHTML;
    });
});
```

```css
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

.target{
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    border:solid black 1px; 
}

#m1, #m2, #m3, #m4, #m5, #m6, #m7, #m8, #m9{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<hr>
<a href="#m1">fea1</a><br><hr>
<a href="#m2">fea2</a><br><hr>
<a href="#m3">fea3</a><br><hr>
<a href="#m4">fea4</a><br><hr>
<a href="#m5">fea5</a><br><hr>
<a href="#m6">fea6</a><br><hr>
<a href="#m7">fea7</a><br><hr>
<a href="#m8">fea8</a><br><hr>
<a href="#m9">fea9</a>
<hr>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<div class="target">

</div>


<div id="m1">dasdasdasd</div>
<div id="m2">dadasdasdasd</div>
<div id="m3">sdasdasds</div>
<div id="m4">dasdasdsad</div>
<div id="m5">dasdasd</div>
<div id="m6">asdasdad</div>
<div id="m7">asdasda</div>
<div id="m8">dasdasd</div>
<div id="m9">dasdasdsgaswa</div>
```

Comment: jQuery is not tagged for this question.

Comment: @RahulDesai you are right! but in the question he writes "How can i do this???" this is an answer showing how he could do it...

Comment: It wouldn't be bad to at least indicate to OP that you have a solution which is jQuery based etc...

Comment: How much heavier does your website get when you use jQuery?

Comment: 241.59 KB uncompressed or 27.85 KB minified and zopflinated. I don't know where you saw such small numbers. Comma in English means thousand, not decimal, separator.

Answer (score 3):

Put for div same name as in href target.

ex: `<div name="link">` and `<a href="#link">`

Comment: *"put for div you want to target."* That doesn't look like a proper sentence. Please [edit] your answer and be clarify it.

Comment: Ah. That is actually unnecessary, because the `id` attribute has the same effect as the `name` attribute in this case.

Answer (score 1):

easy way to do that is like

```
<a href="demo.html#divid">Demo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
  var id=$(this).attr('href');
  var value=$(id).text();
  $(".target").text(value);
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `$`? It's not a standard JavaScript function.

Comment: Used jquery to get result

Comment: Ah. If a question is not tagged with jQuery, you shouldn't provide a jQuery answer. Or at least you should also provide a non-jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

havent tried but this might help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
r=0;s=-1;
$(a).click(function(){
v=$(this).html();
$(a).each(function(){
if($(this).html()==v)
return;
else ++r;
$(div).each(function(){
if(s==r)
$(div).appendTo($(".target")); 
++S;
});

});

});
```

});

Comment: What is `$`? It's not a standard JavaScript function. Also your code is really hard to read. You could indent it properly at least.

Comment: used for selection in jquery

Comment: Then you should at least *mention* that your are using jQuery. But if a question is not tagged with jQuery, you shouldn't provide a jQuery answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you use

> angularjs

you have just to write the right css in order to frame you div
**html code**

```
<div 
style="height:51px;width:111px;margin-left:203px;" 
ng-click="nextDetail()">
</div>
```

JS Code(in your controller):

```
$scope.nextDetail = function()
{
....
}
```