# how to target href to multiple divs?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class, fragment-identifier

I used the method shown in [How to target the href to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328055/how-to-target-the-href-to-div)
to target the href to div. It worked. But I need to add another level.

**HTML**

```
<ul >
    <li class="active"><a href="#m1">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m2">settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="target">
    <div id="m1">
        <ul >
            <li class="active"><a href="#subm1-1" title="Home1">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#subm1-2">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="m2">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#subm2-1" title="Home1">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#subm2-2">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="target123">
    <div id="subm1-1">
        content1
    </div>
    <div id="subm1-2">
        content2
    </div>
    <div id="subm2-1">
        content3
    </div>
    <div id="subm2-2">
        content4
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.target > div {
    display:none;
}

.target > div:target{
    display:block;
}


.target123 > div {
    display:none;
}

.target123 > div:target{
    display:block;
}
```

My issue is when I click on the link, "item 1" in  the content in  appears in the correct place. But the content in  disappears.

How can I stop this?

My divs are positioned next to each other. So one div doesn't overlap the other.

Comment: i don't understand what the :target in your css should mean, did you probably mean .active by any chance?

Comment: This would need scripting (javascript/jquery).  Alternatively, you could make multiple pages, one for each of the elements as f it's selected first.  Then, when they select a second element, show/hide the others.  Would be a pain though.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, this is not possible using the `:target` attribute. The target is always the part of the URL after the #, and there can always only be one target at a time.

This means that whenever you activate a target all the other elements are going to be hidden again. You cannot show contents based on two different targets at the same time using this method.